# Why does dynamically generating an SVG using HTMLObjectElement lead to a Cross-Origin error?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, cross-domain

Consider the following JavaScript snippet:

```
const app = document.getElementById('root');
const svg = `<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1"...`;
const obj = document.createElement('object');

obj.setAttribute('type', 'image/svg+xml');
obj.setAttribute('data', `data:image/svg+xml; base64,${btoa(svg)}`);

app.appendChild(obj);

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(obj.contentDocument.querySelector('svg'));
}, 1500);
```

*(See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4gqby5cy/) for a full example)*

When this runs, the following error is given in the console (Google Chrome):

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLObjectElement': Blocked a frame with origin "https://fiddle.jshell.net" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
>       at setTimeout (https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display:77:19)

With that in mind;

1. Why is this considered a cross-origin request when trying to access the `contentDocument` of the object that has been created entirely dynamically, with no external resources?
2. Is there a way to generate SVGs dynamically in this way, without offending the browsers cross-origin policy?

Comment: Fiddle is a 404. Does the same error happen if you don't base64 encode the svg?

Comment: I've updated the link, markdown was causing it to break: https://jsfiddle.net/4gqby5cy/

Comment: Works for me! Does ist work for you locally?

Comment: @Werner No, this isn't working either locally or otherwise, in any browser. Can you elaborate on your comment. What is working for you exactly? Why do you think it's working for you? What browser and OS are you using? "Works for me", isn't really helpful.

Comment: I am running  62.0.3202.75 (32 bit) and can see the error in my console. Those who can't see it: maybe you have a filter applied to your console display that's hiding the error message? The error described in this question is the correct spec-compliant behavior for trying to access the `contentDocument` of an embedded context when that context has an opaque `data:` origin and the requesting context is a tuple origin. (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#concept-bcc-content-document)

Comment: I suggest you to take a look in this library: snap-svg.js . It's a bit heavy, but is amazing in terms of generate svg's.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem here is that [`data:` URLs are treated as having a unique origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) that differs from the origin of the context that created the embedded `data:` context:

> **Note:** Data URLs are treated as unique opaque origins by modern browsers, rather than inheriting the origin of the settings object responsible for the navigation.

The WHATWG specification describes [how content documents are accessed](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#concept-bcc-content-document), which includes a cross origin check. The [WHATWG same-origin comparison](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/origin.html#same-origin-domain) will never treat a traditional scheme-host-port "tuple" origin as equal to an "opaque" `data:` origin.

Instead, use `Blob` with `URL.createObjectURL` to generate a same-origin temporary URL whose contents will be readable by the outer environment:

```
var svgUrl = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([svg], {'type':'image/svg+xml'}));
obj.setAttribute('data', svgUrl);
```

I don't know the security reason why this approach is allowed while a raw `data:` URL is not, but it does appear to work. (I guess because the generated URL is readable only by the origin that generated it, whereas a `data:` URL doesn't know how to be readable only by the original of its originating context.)

Note also that some versions of Internet Explorer support `createObjectURL` but erroneously treat the generated URLs as having a null origin, which would cause this approach to fail.

Other options are:

1. Don't use a `data:` URL and instead serve the SVG content from the same origin as your page that creates the `<object>` element.
2. Ditch the `<object>` and `contentDocument` altogether and use an [inline `<svg>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg) instead ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/31a9myjg/)):

   ```
   const obj = document.createElement('div');
   obj.innerHTML = svg;
   app.appendChild(obj);
   setTimeout(() => {
     console.log(obj.querySelector('svg'));
   }, 1500);
   ```

   Most browsers support inline `<svg>` elements (notably, IE 9.0+; other browsers much earlier). This means you can do

   ```
   <div>
       <svg>
           ...
       </svg>
   </div>
   ```

   and it will just render the SVG document inside the `<div>` as you would expect.
3. Depending on what you want to do with the SVG, you can [load it into a `DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML) and do DOM exploration/manipulation within the parser.

   ```
   var oParser = new DOMParser();
   var svgDOM = oParser.parseFromString(svg, "text/xml");
   console.log(svgDOM.documentElement.querySelector('path'));
   svgDOM.documentElement.querySelector('path').remove();
   ```

   But the DOM model will be separate from the SVG rendered in the `<object>`. To change the `<object>`, you need to serialize the parsed DOM structure and re-push it to the the `data` property:

   ```
   var oSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
   var sXML = oSerializer.serializeToString(svgDOM);
   obj.setAttribute('data', `data:image/svg+xml; base64,${btoa(sXML)}`);
   ```

   This doesn't seem super performant, because it needs the browser to re-parse a brand-new SVG document, but it will get around the security restrictions.

   Think of the `<object>` as a one-way black hole that can receive SVG information to render, but will not expose any information back. This isn't an informatic problem, though, since you have the information that you just fed into the `<object>`: there's nothing that `contentDocument` can tell you that you don't already know.

   However, if you want to make components within the SVG interactive by attaching listeners to components within the SVG structure that execute code on your main page, I don't think this approach will work. The separation between an `<object>` and its surrounding page has the same kind of embedding relationship as an `<iframe>`.

Comment: *will never treat a traditional scheme-host-port "tuple" origin as equal to an "opaque" data: origin*  Well actually for non content document (e.g media)  dataURI are always treated as same-origin... IMM it's some quirks in the specs.

Comment: @Kaiido Jeez, what a mess -- I guess that's a quirk within the media spec, which might choose to implement its own (`data:`-friendly) same-origin check instead of the referencing the general WHATWG origin-check algorithm. Good tip about the null-origin Blobs; I will edit to note that. Thanks! (Sorry for sniping your answer; I didn't see it until now `:)`)

Comment: Well it makes sense for media to treat dataURIs as same-origin since the only kind of media element that can load/display document (and hence taht could make other queries) is `<img>`, and that there are a lot of stricter measures applied to documents in this element (no interaction, no scripts, no external resources etc.), whereas when loaded in an `<object>` all the above are allowed. I'm not really clear though as to what they thought was the difference between a dataURI and a blobURI, since we can build a blobURI from a  dataURI...

Comment: And for your workaround, I think the DOMParser is actually not a bad idea, for browsers without blobURI support, you just missed one step: append the parsed SVG inside an `about:blank` object's document. From there you will be able to manipulate it like if it were from the same origin. (didn't tested in IE though)

Comment: FWIW, the difference between a data URL and blob URL is that the latter is much harder to construct by attackers.

Comment: if your `[svg]` is a byte[] then use this for the first argument in the new Blob invocation `[new Uint8Array(BYTEARRAY)]`

Answer (score 3):

because the object tag defines an embedded object within the HTML document, it's not part of the document itself, and therefore must respect the CORS like a frame

[Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object) clearly states that the content of the object tag is considered an external resource

> The HTML  element represents an **external resource**, which can be treated as an image, a nested browsing context, or a resource to be handled by a plugin.