# removeEventListener for object data load

Tags: javascript, svg, addeventlistener, dom-events

I have added an event listener to catch the loading of an SVG after a user action.

HTML

```
<object id="mySVG" type="image/svg+xml" data="default.svg"></object>
```

JS

```
mySVG = document.getElementById('mySVG');
mySVG.addEventListener('load', function () {
  // work with SVG contentDocument
});
mySVG.setAttribute('data', 'new.svg');
```

After another user action, I am clearing out the SVG by loading a blank inline SVG

```
var svgUrl = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(['<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="700" height="700"/>'], {'type':'image/svg+xml'}));
mySVG.setAttribute('data', svgUrl);
```

I looks like setting this blank SVG is also triggering the load event, which is undesirable. So I tried

```
mySVG.removeEventListener('load');
```

This gives me the error

> TypeError: Not enough arguments to EventTarget.removeEventListener.

What is the correct syntax for removeEventListener in this context?

edit: method to set the blank SVG was incorrect, corrected after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929730/why-does-dynamically-generating-an-svg-using-htmlobjectelement-lead-to-a-cross-o).

Comment: Did you try looking up the docs to see what you need to pass to `removeEventListener`? It might be informative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should name your function and then pass it as the second argument both to `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`, like so:

```js
mySVG = document.getElementById('mySVG');

function loadFunction() {
  // work with SVG contentDocument
}

mySVG.addEventListener('load', loadFunction);
mySVG.setAttribute('data', 'new.svg');

mySVG.setAttribute('data', 'data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22700%22%20height%3D%22700%22%2F%3E');


mySVG.removeEventListener('load', loadFunction);
```

```html
<object id="mySVG" type="image/svg+xml" data="default.svg"></object>
```

`removeEventListener` requires at least two arguments, the event type (`'load'`) and the listener to remove, so you have to reference the listener that was added previously for it to ve removed.

Answer (score 0):

mySVG.removeEventListener('load'); should have a target as second parameter on which it listens events